# kubernetes - How do I get one job to work with multiple nodes?

Tags: kubernetes, cluster-computing

Currently, when I create and run deployment, I only work on one node.

I want to work on one task at the same time using Kubernetes.

I want all nodes to work like one computer.

[image]

Comment: I guess, Hadoop cluster fits your task definition better than Kubernetes cluster: https://databricks.com/glossary/hadoop-cluster

Comment: PS: Kubernetes is not designed to join several nodes into one big virtual CPU. Each Kubernetes node acts as a separate computer, managed by the master node control plane. You can run several instances of your task, one on each node if you will, or create higher level controller to manage those instances. Your application have to be able to scale horizontally (splitting a big task to small parts to execute them independently).

Answer (score 0):

Kubernetes is about managing containers and scheduling them to run across a cluster, not about “jobs” per se. Have a look at MapReduce and Apache Spark.

Answer (score 0):

First you need to understand more about Kubernetes and why your understanding might be a bit misleading for you concept. Kubernetes is an container orchestration tool that automates many of the manual processes involved in deploying, managing, and scaling containerized applications.

In other words, you can cluster together groups of hosts running Linux containers, and K8s helps you manage those clusters. To process some kind of job, data you will need a software that runs on kubernetes.

The next step that you might want to look into is [distributed computing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Distributed_computing#:%7E:text=Distributed%20computing%20is%20a%20field%20of%20computer%20science%20that%20studies%20distributed%20systems.&text=In%20distributed%20computing,%20a%20problem,each%20other%20via%20message%20passing.) concept and distributed computing model called [MapReduce](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MapReduce).

MapReduce was introduce by Google to meet the demand of large set of users for its applications. Its used to write write scalable applications that can do parallel processing to process a large amount of data on a large cluster of commodity hardware servers. Hadoop is software that has adopted MapReduce and is capable of running it`s programs in various languages (Python, Ruby, C++).

Take a look on this [medium article](https://medium.com/digitalwing/development-of-a-distributed-computing-system-based-on-mapreduce-and-kubernetes-837fc7f112f9) about distributed computing system based on MapReduce and Kubernetes.