# How do I specify a minimum number of schedulable pods in kubernetes?

Tags: kubernetes

I want to run multiple jobs in a kubernetes cluster, but the total resource requirements exceed the size of the cluster, and the requirements of one job span multiple nodes. How do I avoid a livelock where all jobs have some resources, but none have enough to complete?

For example, suppose I have 4 nodes, each with 1 GB of memory available. I want to submit 2 jobs, each of which requires 3 GB of memory to complete, split across 3 pods that require 1 GB each. The correct solution here would be to run the jobs sequentially, how do I ensure this happens?

I want to avoid the situation where both jobs schedule two pods each, using up the entire cluster, while the remaining pod of each job is stuck in the `Pending` state, as no more resources are available. Because the jobs cannot complete using only 2 GB of memory, the system is now incapable of making progress.

## Related Features

Some features I've looked at that don't seem to be suitable:

1. [Pod Disruption Budget](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/run-application/configure-pdb/) - this is for ensuring that the number of pods never goes below X, but doesn't have any effect when scheduling the pods initially
2. [Pod Affinity](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/scheduling-eviction/assign-pod-node/#inter-pod-affinity-and-anti-affinity) - this can ensure I schedule pods in a region where a matching pod is running, but I can't require two or more pods. I'm also not sure if affinity would be satisfied if no pods are running but they are scheduled.
3. [Pod Topology Spread Constraints](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/scheduling-eviction/topology-spread-constraints/) - This is to ensure that the numbers of pods scheduled in multiple regions is always within N of each other, but again I can't specify a required minimum.

## Possible Solution

It looks like a custom scheduler is needed. [Kube Batch](https://github.com/kubernetes-sigs/kube-batch/blob/master/doc/usage/tutorial.md) looks like a possible solution for this, supporting a `minMember` attribute. I will test this and submit it as a self-answer, unless anyone can chime in with more detail.

Comment: if the job requires 3 gb of memory and you have 3 pods with gb each it might not start to begin with as you are requesting 3 gb for the job and no node has the availability. (unless the job is broken up).  Each node is like it's own computer. If you need more power you need to designate a more powerful node pool. If you are splitting it with something like mapreduce then eventually at least one job should fail and the other will scoop up the node and things should pick up again.
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62483316/kubernetes-how-do-i-get-one-job-to-work-with-multiple-nodes

Comment: Yes, exactly - each job is broken up into three pods, which require 1 GB each. I don't think the failure mechanism helps, because if I retry jobs (since they should all complete), or have >2 jobs, I don't want to have all but one job fail.

Comment: This is not a map-reduce job, the three pods in a job can't make independent progress. All three must be scheduled at the same time for any of them to make progress.

Comment: So they are 3 jobs technically. Can you have your cluster autoscale?

Comment: No, autoscaling is not an option. There are 2 jobs (that are independent). Each job consists of 3 pods (that must be all be scheduled for the job to make progress). The problem is that I don't have enough resources to schedule all 6 pods at the same time.

Comment: What is triggering the job?  What I would do is keep the job state and queue in an external resource like a database and have a job just check the database for new jobs and start it if none are currently running. When the job ends, remove it from the queue.

Comment: The jobs are user-submitted (container image + CLI arguments), and have to run different container images, so I can't keep a persistent deployment that takes tasks from a queue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easy solution is to assign each a job a PriorityClass so that one job can preempt the other if needed:

https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/scheduling-eviction/pod-priority-preemption/

However, this means one job will always have priority over the other. If you need them to run in the order they were received, you need a queue job system. Here is one you can try:

https://github.com/kubernetes-sigs/kueue

Using kueue, you would create a `Workload` for each job as they come in and add it to the same `LocalQueue`.